# Find the number of consecutively increasing elements in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got a problem in TalentBuddy, which sounds like this

> A student's performance in lab activities should always improve, but that is not always the case.
>   Since progress is one of the most important metrics for a student, let’s write a program that computes the longest period of increasing performance for any given student.
>   For example, if his grades for all lab activities in a course are: 9, 7, 8, 2, 5, 5, 8, 7 then the longest period would be 4 consecutive labs (2, 5, 5, 8).

So far, I seem too confused to work the code. The only thing that I worked is

```
def longest_improvement(grades):
    res = 0
    for i in xrange(len(grades) - 2):
        while grades[i] <= grades[i + 1]:
            res += 1
            i += 1
    print res
```

But that prints `17`, rather than `6` when `grades = [1, 7, 2, 5, 6, 9, 11, 11, 1, 6, 1]`.

How to work out the rest of the code? Thanks

Comment: I think Tim used this idea in Tim Sort... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved with some old-fashioned tail-recursion:

```
grades = [1, 7, 2, 5, 6, 9, 11, 11, 1, 6, 1]

def streak(grades):
    def streak_rec(longest, challenger, previous, rest):
        if rest == []:             # Base case
            return max(longest, challenger)
        elif previous <= rest[0]:  # Streak continues
            return streak_rec(longest, challenger + 1, rest[0], rest[1:])
        else:                      # Streak is reset
            return streak_rec(max(longest, challenger), 1, rest[0], rest[1:])

    return streak_rec(0, 0, 0, grades)

print streak(grades) # => 6
print streak([2])    # => 1
```

Comment: Easy to understand, honestly I forgot to use tail-recursion. Nicely done! I marked this as the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the current solution involves yield and maps and additional memory overhead, it's probably a good idea to at least mention the simple solution:

```
def length_of_longest_sublist(lst):
    max_length, cur_length = 1, 1
    prev_val = lst[0]
    for val in lst[1:]:
        if val >= prev_val :
            cur_length += 1
        else:
            max_length = max(max_length, cur_length)
            cur_length = 1
        prev_val = val
    return max(max_length, cur_length)
```

We could reduce that code by getting the previous value directly:

```
def length_of_longest_sublist2(lst):
    max_length, cur_length = int(bool(lst)), int(bool(lst)) 
    for prev_val, val in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
        if val >= prev_val:
            cur_length += 1
        else:
            max_length = max(max_length, cur_length)
            cur_length = 1
    return max(max_length, cur_length)
```

which is a nice trick to know (and allows it to easily return the right result for an empty list), but confusing to people who don't know the idiom.

Answer (score 1):

This method uses fairly basic python and the return statement can be quickly modified so that you have a list of all the streak lengths.

```
def longest_streak(grades):
    if len(grades) < 2:
        return len(grades)
    else:
        start, streaks = -1, []
        for idx, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(grades, grades[1:])):
            if x > y:
                streaks.append(idx - start)
                start = idx
        else:
            streaks.append(idx - start + 1) 
        return max(streaks)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it this way:

```
from itertools import groupby
from funcy import pairwise, ilen 

def streak(grades):
    if len(grades) <= 1: 
        return len(grades)
    orders = (x <= y for x, y in pairwise(grades))
    return max(ilen(l) for asc, l in groupby(orders) if asc) + 1
```

Very explicit: `orders` is an iterator of `True`s for ascending pairs and `False`s for descending ones. Then we need just find a longest list of ascending and add 1.

Comment: I love it :) Very nicely thought out!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same `res` variable in each iteration of the inner `while` loop. You probably want to reset it, and keep the highest intermediate result in a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late, but here's my *Updated* version:

```
from funcy import ilen, ireductions


def streak(last, x):
    if last and x >= last[-1]:
        last.append(x)
        return last
    return [x]


def longest_streak(grades):
    xs = map(ilen, ireductions(streak, grades, None))
    return xs and max(xs) or 1

grades = [1, 7, 2, 5, 6, 9, 11, 11, 1, 6, 1]
print longest_streak(grades)
print longest_streak([2])
```

I decided in the end to not only produce a correct
version without bugs, but to use a library I quite like [funcy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcy) :)

**Output:**

```
6
1
```

Comment: The generator could probably be simplified though and I suspect the ``funcy`` or ``toolz`` (*or even itertools*) libraries would help greatly to generalize and simplify the problem :)

Comment: This must be the most complicated solution to this problem I've ever seen. But I assume if it works^^

Comment: IHMO it's not complex at all. It's doing basic partitioning of the input list. This could be simplified a lot by using good functional libraries.

Comment: By what measurement is this easier than the obvious solution? Just posted that one for comparison. And yes that one could be simplified by implementing it recursively, but in python that's generally not that great an idea.

Comment: I really don't think your solution is any easier to understand :)

Comment: Well it was complicated enough that you introduced a bug: Try with a single-argument list :)

Comment: Haha nice edge case :) Oops :)

Comment: See my answer for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not as efficient as previous answers, but it's short :P

```
diffgrades = np.diff(grades)
maxlen = max([len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(diffgrades, lambda x: x >= 0) if k]) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the idea of @M4rtini to use `itertools.groupby`.

```
def longest_streak(grades):
    from itertools import groupby    
    if len(grade) > 1:
        streak = [x <= y for x, y in zip(grades,grades[1:])]
        return max([sum(g, 1) for k, g in groupby(streak) if k])
    else:
        return len(grades)
```